# Query to get translation for each languages

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me to create query. I have table with languages like

```
Id   Code
---------
1    EN
2    DE
3    RU
```

and table with translations

```
Id  Code  LanguageId  Value
------------------------------------------
1   1     1           EnglishTranslation
2   1     3           RussianTranslation
3   2     1           EnglishTranslation
4   2     2           DeutschTranslation
5   3     1           EnglishTranslation
```

I'm trying to get this result

```
 Id  Code  LanguageId  Value
 ------------------------------------------
 1   1     1           EnglishTranslation
 1   1     2           NULL
 2   1     3           RussianTranslation
 3   2     1           EnglishTranslation
 4   2     2           DeutschTranslation
 4   2     3           NULL
 5   3     1           EnglishTranslation
 5   3     2           NULL
 5   3     3           NULL
```

Need to get translations for all languages by `Code` from Translations table So far I try

```
  select 
    T.id, T.Code, L.Id, T.Value
  from Languages L
  left join Translations T on T.LanguageId = L.Id
```

but I got not expected result. Could you please suggest

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9bed/1

Comment: You logic is unclear. Why is your second row null?

Comment: Your desired output seems strange. for id 1 and 4 you get two rows, one with a null value, for id 2 and 3 you get only one row, and for id 5 you get three rows. I don't understand this logic.

Comment: @plaidDK Second row null because I do not have translation for language 2 - Deutsch

Comment: @Mr.Potkin But you dont have one for russia as well?

Comment: Let me second, I'll fix

Comment: @ZoharPeled Need to get translations for all languages by Code from Translations table

Comment: Oh, I see that now. The Id confused me.

Comment: @Mr.Potkin I pushed an answer. Please execute my answer and if it is really helpful for you, then accept my answer and vote up it. I'll vote up your nice question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` operator to construct a cartesian product of `(LanguageId, Code)` pairs, and left-join translation table to it:

```
SELECT
    t.Id, y.Code, x.LanguageId, t.Value
FROM
    ((SELECT Id AS LanguageId FROM Languages) AS x
     CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT(Code) AS Code FROM Translations) AS y)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Translations t ON y.Code=t.Code AND x.LanguageId=t.LanguageId
ORDER BY t.Code, t.LanguageId
```

Note that this wouldn't produce a valid translation Id for rows missing from `Translations`, i.e. the result would look like this:

```
   Id  Code  LanguageId  Value
---------------------------------------------
   1   1     1           EnglishTranslation
NULL   1     2           NULL
   2   1     3           RussianTranslation
   3   2     1           EnglishTranslation
   4   2     2           DeutschTranslation
NULL   2     3           NULL
   5   3     1           EnglishTranslation
NULL   3     2           NULL
NULL   3     3           NULL
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9bed/26)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue and got the result that you expected.

Run the below query:

```
SELECT
(CASE 
    WHEN T.Id is null and lc.Code = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN T.Id is null and lc.Code = 2 THEN 4
    WHEN T.Id is null and lc.Code = 3 THEN 5
    ELSE T.Id
END) as Id, 
lc.Code, lc.Id as LanguageId, T.Value from 
(SELECT x.Id, y.Code from (SELECT Id FROM Languages) x cross join (SELECT DISTINCT(Code) as Code FROM Translations) y) as lc
left outer join Translations T ON lc.Id = T.LanguageId and lc.Code = T.Code
order by Id, Code, LanguageId
```

You can also see the solution in the below link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9bed/30

Hopefully it will work as you like.